# Regex Unordered Repeated match

Tags: python, regex

I want to express: "There's three separated '1's, one separated '2' in this sentence."

I want all of these cases match:

```
a 1 b 1 c 1 d 2
asdf 2 asdf 1 asdf 1 asdf 1
a 1 b 1 c 2 1
ab1c:1, cb2a:2, ca2c:1, 1
```

(I can't use `.count()` since the characters between digits can be anything, including digits. See below for further explanation.)

This can be expressed like this:

```py
for i in range(3):
    # match separated '1' and eliminate the result in the target string
    # if there's no match result, it doesn't match
# match separated '2'
```

, but I want to express this in one regex.
I found out that I can use
`^(?=.*` *(Input characters here)* `)(?=.*` *(and so on)* `).*$`
for unordered match.

But using
`^(?=.*1)(?=.*1)(?=.*1)(?=.*2).*$`
won't work here since `?=` doesn't consume characters.
It fails not to match:

```
ab 1 cd 1 ef 2
```

Further explanation:

What I really trying to do is `^(?=.*[^\d-]1\b)`*(three times)*`(?=.*[^\d-]2\b).*$`

Comment: there is a robust solution with 2 short regex patterns though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a negated character class matching not a digit will not work as for example the number 2 is after number 1 in the first example.

You might match three times the 1 and one time the 2 making use of lookarounds to makes sure what is on the left and on the right is not a digit:

```
^(?=(?:.*(?<!\d)1(?!\d)){3})(?=.*(?<!\d)2(?!\d)).+$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(?:.*(?<!\d)1(?!\d)){3}` Repeat 3 times matching a 1 not surrounded by digits
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `.*(?<!\d)2(?!\d)` Match a 2 not surrounded by digits
- `)` Close lookahead
- `.+` Match any char except a newline 1+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WgVyvc/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class and a simple regex:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

S = '''
a 1 b 1 c 1 d 2
asdf 2 asdf 1 asdf 1 asdf 1
a 1 b 1 c 2 1
ab1c:1, cb2a:2, ca2c:1, 1
ab 1 cd 1 ef 2
'''    
rx = re.compile(r'\b[12]\b')
c = Counter()
o = t = 0
for s in S.split('\n'):
    c.update(int(m.group()) for m in rx.finditer(s))
    if c[1] - o == 3 and c[2] - t == 1: # use >= instead of == if you need it
        print(s)
    o, t = c[1], c[2]
```

**Output:**

```
a 1 b 1 c 1 d 2
asdf 2 asdf 1 asdf 1 asdf 1
a 1 b 1 c 2 1
ab1c:1, cb2a:2, ca2c:1, 1
```

Demo on [Rextester](https://rextester.com/NRXIY23446).